# Is it possible to output JavaScript array elements as hyperlinks in a table in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, hyperlink

This is the code I have done so far. I want to hyperlink the websites so that when the array is outputted as a table in HTML, the websites will be clickable and link to their respective webpages.

JavaScript:

```
var beds = new Array(3);
beds[0] = ["Spring Mattress",      "http://factorymattresstexas.com/specials/spring-air/"];
beds[1] = ["Rest Lumbar Support", "http://factorymattresstexas.com/specials/beautyrest-lumbar-support"];
beds[2] = ["Beauty Rest", "http://factorymattresstexas.com/specials/simmons-beautyrest/"];
```

HTML:

```
var table = document.getElementById("table");
var body = document.createElement("tbody");

table.appendChild(tbody);
beds.forEach(function(items) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    items.forEach(function(item) {
        var cell = document.createElement("td");
        cell.textContent = item;
        row.appendChild(cell);
    });
    table.appendChild(row);
});




<table id="table">
  <tr id="tbody">
    <th>Mattress Type</th>
    <th>Link</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How about instead on setting the `text` for the cell, create a link element and append that instead

Comment: Yes, it is definitely possible.  Do you know how to create a single link (`A` element) out of a single string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you asked, just create an `a` tag with content and modify his href attribute.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table id="table">
      <tr id="tbody">
        <th>Mattress Type</th>
        <th>Link</th>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    var body = document.createElement("tbody");

    var beds = new Array(3);
    beds[0] = ["Spring Mattress",      "http://factorymattresstexas.com/specials/spring-air/"];
    beds[1] = ["Rest Lumbar Support", "http://factorymattresstexas.com/specials/beautyrest-lumbar-support"];
    beds[2] = ["Beauty Rest", "http://factorymattresstexas.com/specials/simmons-beautyrest/"];

    table.appendChild(tbody);
    beds.forEach(function(items) {
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        var cell1 = document.createElement("td");
        cell1.textContent = items[0];
        row.appendChild(cell1);

        var cell2 = document.createElement("td");
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.text = items[1]
        link.href = items[1]
        cell2.append(link)

        row.appendChild(cell2);

        table.appendChild(row);
    });

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT :**

Here is a version with only one column, pick the one you pref :

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table id="table">
      <tr id="tbody">
        <th>Mattress Type</th>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    var body = document.createElement("tbody");

    var beds = new Array(3);
    beds[0] = ["Spring Mattress",      "http://factorymattresstexas.com/specials/spring-air/"];
    beds[1] = ["Rest Lumbar Support", "http://factorymattresstexas.com/specials/beautyrest-lumbar-support"];
    beds[2] = ["Beauty Rest", "http://factorymattresstexas.com/specials/simmons-beautyrest/"];

    table.appendChild(tbody);
    beds.forEach(function(items) {
        var row = document.createElement("tr");

        var cell = document.createElement("td");

        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.text = items[0];
        link.href = items[1]

        cell.append(link);

        row.appendChild(cell)

        table.appendChild(row);
    });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm using the code that you've provided above but I'm getting an error message: Object doesn't support property or method 'append' which is referring to cell2.append(link)

Comment: Use appendChild instead of append if it doesn't work, i tested my code on Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create an "anchor" element to make it a clickable link.

```
    var hyperlink = document.createElement("a");
    hyperlink.textContent = items[0];
    hyperlink.href = items[1];
```

I'm not sure why you want two separate columns for this, something like the above will take an "items" array from `beds` and make a readable, clickable link from it.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a link element and append that to the cell, instead of just the text:

```
beds.forEach(function(item) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  var cell = document.createElement("td");
  var cell2 = document.createElement("td");
  var link = document.createElement("a");

  cell.textContent = item[0];
  link.href = item[1];
  link.textContent = "click me";

  cell2.appendChild(link);
  row.appendChild(cell);
  row.appendChild(cell2);
  table.appendChild(row);
});
```

[Here is a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/fg18mt6L/)

Comment: Thank you this code works great! A quick question: what if I have more elements in between columns 0 and 1? Say for example I had other attributes about the mattresses like size, weight, thickness, etc. How would I output all of these attributes in a table before outputting the URL?

Comment: Also I'm not able to get the textContent to output any information in the table (blank cell), however, the hyperlink is working.

Comment: @AndrewC: If you have more columns, then you just add a new cell for each one and put whatever you want in it. You can try `innerText` instead: `link.innerText = "click me";` for example

Answer (score 0):

try this. i am assuming that item[0] will return name and item[1] will return link

```
  items.forEach(function(item) {
   var table = '<tr id="tbody"><th>"' + item[0] + '</th>'
   '<th><a href="'+item[1]+'">Link</a></th>'
   '</tr>';
    table.appendChild(table);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

His is an edit from @BooDooPerson answer.

```
beds.forEach(function(items) {
        var row = document.createElement("tr");

        items.forEach(function(item) {
            var cell = document.createElement("td"),
                   hyperlink = document.createElement("a");

             hyperlink.textContent = items[0];
             hyperlink.href = items[1];;
             cell.textContent = item;
             row.appendChild(cell);
        });

        table.appendChild(row);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to put the table with the specific id BEFORE writing the script. Coz you have to introduce the ID first before searching them.

Here's my version, hope I didn't change too much.

```
<table id="table"></table>

<script>
var table = document.getElementById("table");

var beds = new Array(3);
beds[0] = ["Spring Mattress",      "http://factorymattresstexas.com/specials/spring-air/"];
beds[1] = ["Rest Lumbar Support", "http://factorymattresstexas.com/specials/beautyrest-lumbar-support"];
beds[2] = ["Beauty Rest", "http://factorymattresstexas.com/specials/simmons-beautyrest/"];

var addHTML = `
              <tr id="tbody">
                <th>Mattress Type</th>
                <th>Link</th>
              </tr>
              `;
beds.forEach(function(items) {
    addHTML += `
              <tr>
                <td>${items[0]}</td>
                <td><a href="${items[1]}">${items[1]}</a></td>
              </tr>
              `;
});
table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',addHTML);
</script>
```